# SQLite in anaconda

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda

I was just wondering, if sqlite is part of the python standard library, why is there a package in the anaconda repositories?

- wouldn't the python installed through anaconda already have sqlite built-in?
- When using python, which sqlite is it even using, the built-in or the one distributed with conda?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sqlite

thanks

Comment: It looks like the conda library contains the sqlite shared libraries that are not technically part of the python package (although most systems have them already installed).

Comment: I think you are right ... some extensions seem to be turned off by default in the normal python distribution (e.g. full text)... perhaps those are part of the conda package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda is a generic package manager, not a Python one. The `sqlite` package is purely the CLI, header files, and pre-compiled libraries for linking against.

The `python` package in Conda links against the `sqlite` libraries, and declares it as a dependency so that installing `python` will also install `sqlite`.

Comment: Why would the python package in conda need the sqlite, considering the library is already shipped along the python standard library (which is assume is fully part of the python package itself). If I were to install python directly (without conda), i would still get sqlite with it.

Comment: Python's `sqlite` *module* is an interface to use the binary `sqlite` *library*. Conda is merely splitting these components modularly, so other packages in the Conda ecosystem can similarly use the same `sqlite` binary without duplication.

Comment: Answer is good. So here is my understanding, Sqlite is a DLL file, you can find it in the DLL folder of Anaconda or even in the DLL folder of a standard python install (without anaconda). The standard library of python comes with the necessary module that facilitates the use of Sqlite in python and uses this DLL.